# NServiceBus - how to register my own modules with autofac

Tags: nservicebus, autofac

Since NServiceBus internally uses autofac, should I register my bindings through nservicebus or should I just install AutoFac as usual with modules and bindings? If so, since I have a windows service project, where do I initiate the autofac setup? In my EndPointConfig.cs?

Note that this is for my own bindings, not IBus which registers itself automagically.

Answer (score 0):

With all the containers available, there will be an overload in the endpoint config to pass in an instance of the container which should be loaded with all your stuff.  From there, NSB will add in its internal stuff and everything will be available to you.

```
Configure.With().AutofacBuilder(builder)...
```

Comment: Is there a way that you can get access to the container when you receive an event? (In the implementation of IHandleMessages<T>.) I have a multi-tenant application, and the event contains the domain that the message relates to. Prior to using NSB, I was solving the problem by passing the domain as a parameter on BeginLifetimeScope when each event was received. I need the domain to look up the correct connection strings for the particular tenant.

Comment: Couple of options, could you use the message headers instead?  Another thing to look into would be using IManageUnitsOfWork, which would get you inserted before and after every message.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up solving the problem by using message mutators to add the domain into the message header. I then set up my own Autofac container which I registered on init. The host name provider is registered with a delegate method that resolves IBus and then gets the host name from the header, using CurrentMessageContext on the bus. As long as it's registered per lifetime scope, everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I have a separate class which implements INeedInitialization. In it's Init method I configure the DI.

For example:

```
using NServiceBus;
using NServiceBus.Config;

public class DependencyInjection  : INeedInitialization
{

    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.Instance.Configurer.RegisterSingleton<ISomeInterface>(
            new SomeClassImplementingInterface());
    }
}
```

Comment: Still your NServiceBus endpoint has to have a reference to the implementing type: "new SomeClassImplementingInterface()" which is all but IoC. What you need there really, is assembly scanning with some kind of marker interface/attribute